# How to Fill Column Loop? VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

So i would like to make a loop that autofills the same column throughout all worksheets. I recorded the macro but obviously that is a lot of code. I tried to use a loop, but some of the variables i want to autofill with have numbers at the end (e.g. "ULA2"), And so with auto fill it would make the entire column ULA2, ULA3, ULA4,... How can I correct this? Here is my code:

```
Sheets("ULA2").Select
    Range("F2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "ULA2"
    Range("F4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "ULA2"
    Range("F5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "ULA2"
    Range("F6").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "ULA2"
    Range("F7").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "ULA2"
    Range("F8").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "ULA2"
    Range("F9").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "ULA2"
    Range("F10").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "ULA2"
    Range("F11").Select

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
Range("F2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("F2:F" & LastRow), Type:=xlFillDefault

Sheets("BO").Select
    Range("F2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "BO"
    Range("F2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("F2:F"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("F2:F").Select
```

Comment: so you just want all of row `F` to be filled with `ULA2` or `BO` to match the sheet's name??

Comment: `Sheets("ULA2").Range("F2:F11").Value = "ULA2"` - assuming you didn't mean to skip F3

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 Yes, there are 16 more sheets, but i just put in two sheets for a small sample. But ideally, whatever the sheet's name is, I would like it to fill all of column F, excluding F1 in every sheet.

Comment: @TimWilliams The problem is, is that on different worksheets F11 is not the finishing cell of the column.

Comment: Your posted code is a little confusing - is there already existing content in the column you're "filling", and if so what exactly are you filling?

Comment: Why does the first worksheet skip F3 but the second does not?

Comment: Hi Emalee, if you feel that someone's answer here solved your problem, please consider accepting it as the best answer using the big checkbox :)

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 Thank you for the reminder!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick. It will loop through all of your sheets and set row `F` (after the header and down to the bottom) equal to the name of the sheet

```
Dim i As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

For i = 1 To Worksheets.count
    With Sheets(i)
        LastRow = .Cells(Rows.count, "F").End(xlUp).row
        .Range("F2:F" & LastRow).Value2 = .Name
    End With
Next i
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this on all worksheets you can use the following:

```
For Each mySht In Application.Worksheets
    mySht.Range("F2:F" & mySht.UsedRange.Row + mySht.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1).Value = mySht.Name
Next mySht
```